# Cancellations in partial sum of Ramanujan tau function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

I am interested in partial sums $$T(x) = \sum_{n \le x} \tau(n)$$

Where $\tau$ is [Ramanujan's Tau function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_tau_function).

It is known that $|\tau(n)| = O( n^{5.5+\epsilon})$ for $\epsilon>0$ and that this is essentially the best bound. Hence a trivial bound on $T(x)$ is $O( x^{6.5+\epsilon})$. But $\tau$ oscillates its sign, so there seems to exist further cancellations.

Indeed, I did some calculations in my computer and I found that for $x$ up to $10^6$, $|T(x)|$ is never greater than $x^{5.73}$.

> Are there any better upper bounds for T(x)?

I couldn't find any sources.

I am interested mostly because of the implications for the "Ramanujan L-function":

$$L(\Delta,s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\tau(n)}{n^s}$$

The upper bound $\tau(n) = O(n^{5.5+\epsilon})$ is only enough to define this function for $\Re(s) > 6.5$, but by partial summation:

$$L(\Delta,s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} T(n)(\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^s})$$

Hence an upper bound for $T(x)$ of the kind $O(x^r)$ would be enough to extend this function to $\Re(s)>r$. So upper bounds better than $x^{6.5}$ for $T(x)$ will further extend this function.

If the bound holds for any $r<6$, that would prove $L(\Delta,s)$ is holomorphic on $\Re(s)>r$, which together with the symmetry that this function has about the strip $\sigma = 6$ would be enough to extend it for the whole plane and prove it is entire. I was also not able to confirm whether $L(\Delta,s)$ is entire or not, so I would also appreciate sources for that.

Comment: Computer calculations show nothing in this case. Big $O$ hides constant, so if constant would be $10^{36}$, then you could incorrectly suspect that it is $O(x)$.

Comment: It is well known that this $L$-function is entire. Read any introductory text on modular forms or automorphic forms.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to assure you that the bound $T(x)=O(x^{5.73})$ is incorrect. Corollary 5.2 of [my recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.00006) indicates that

$$
T(x)=\sum_{n\le x}\tau(n)=\Omega_\pm(x^{5.75}),
$$

which means that

$$
\liminf_{x\to\infty}{T(x)\over x^{5.75}}<0<\limsup_{x\to\infty}{T(x)\over x^{5.75}}
$$

This result can also be generalized to sum of $\tau(n)$ over arithmetic progressions. Namely, Corollary 5.3 of the same paper indicates that for all $q\in\mathbb N$ there exists some integer $h$ satisfying $(h,q)=1$ and

$$
T(x;q,h)=\sum_{\substack{n\le x\\n\equiv h\pmod q}}\tau(n)=\Omega(x^{5.75}).
$$

That is to say

$$
\limsup_{x\to\infty}{|T(x;q,h)|\over x^{5.75}}>0.
$$